# JS button pressed and resize iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, iframe

When i pressed a button in the iframe, it disappears the tag but doesnt resize the iframe size. when the ajax is done should call the AjustResizeIframeHeight method in the other page
Any suggestion to do that?

**UPDATE**

page with iframe

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function resizeIframe(obj) {
 obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
function AdjustIframeHeight(i) { document.getElementById("form-iframe").style.height = parseInt(i) + "px"; }
</script>

<iframe id"form-iframe" width="100%" style="border: none" src="{{ notes }}"  onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);'>
</iframe>
```

content the iframe:

```
<a href="#" onclick="xpto2(1,{{ n.id }});parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(parentNode)" >Don't show again</a>

<script>
    function xpto2(status,noteid) {
       var request =  $.ajax({
           ....
       });
        request.done(function() {
           window.parent.AdjustIframeHeight();
        });
}
</script>
```

Added the `window.parent.AdjustIframeHeight()` in the ajax function, but it says "unresolved function or method"

Answer (score 0):

1. When you AJAX call is done, it does nothing because you have an empty function.
2. `getElementById("form-    iframe")` will find nothing because there is no element with id `form-    iframe`.
3. If the page in your iframe has the same host, protocol and port, you should be able to access the function via `window.parent.AdjustIframeHeight()`.
   If host, protocol or port do not match, you have to use [`Window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) from your iframe and listen for `message` events on the parent page.

Comment: I follow your suggestion but i says "unresolved function or method"

Comment: What does it show in the console if you run (from your iframe) `console.log(window.parent)`? And did you try the `postMessage` too?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**
The solution was to add a div and then call the div to the method

page with iframe

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function resizeIframe(obj) {
obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
function AdjustIframeHeight(i)     {parent.AdjustIframeHeight(document.getElementById("page").scrollHeight);
</script>

<iframe id"form-iframe" width="100%" style="border: none" src="{{ notes }}"  onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);'>
</iframe>
```

content the iframe:

```
<div id="page"> 
<a href="#" onclick="xpto2(1,{{ n.id }});parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(parentNode)" >Don't show again</a>
<\div>
<script>
function xpto2(status,noteid) {
      ....
   });
    request.done(function() {
       request.done(function() {
            parent.AdjustIframeHeight(document.getElementById("page").scrollHeight);
    });
}
</script>
```